# Using Angular Templates

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a template to be rendered with angular and a node js application.

I want to make some kind of require('angular'); from my node application and use it's compile service to compile an email template and send the email with node.

Is this possible? Or is it better to look for other alternatives such as this one http://documentup.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment as far as I know no one has figured out how to correctly render angular templates in node. There has been discussion about it, but I don't know of any working module available. For emails, use one of the many readily available templating libraries (mustache is at least similar in syntax to angular). Angular is really geared toward dynamic, interactive DOM changes which you don't need on the server, so it's generally not that great a fit. Rendering email templates and sending them with node is however very straightforward and there are many good modules available to help with that.